# Build and Run on Ubuntu VM

Tags: linux, build, virtual-machine, apple-m1, utm

I just installed UTM on my M1 Macbook and am running ubuntu-20.04.4 as a Virtual Machine. I've been trying to build and run a code given for an assignment, as requested by the course professor.

An issue rose when I got 'make: g++: Command not found'. I therefore installed Developer tools through the command 'apt-get install build-essential'.

**This is where I need help**. The tools were installed, but running the 'make' command gave a different error 'g++: error: unrecognized command line error: -m64'.

Note: All the necessary files to build and run the code are provided (e.g: Makefile and Cpp file). I really just have to build and run to see the program output.

Comment: Well, you could ask Google, what g++ -m64 means. ..... And you can edit away all `-m64` from the Makefile, and see what happens .....